# Unable to launch Azure IoT Edge module into specified docker network with NetworkId

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I'm trying to launch modules on my IoT edge device, into some specified docker networks that I've already set up.

Looking at the README here ([github iotedge/edge-agent](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/tree/master/edge-agent)), it seems to indicate I can set a `NetworkId` environment variable on the `edgeAgent` module, and that will cause it to launch new modules into that docker network.

On my edge host, I have the following networks:

```
user@iot-edge:~$ sudo docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
79a913b7939e        azure-iot-edge      bridge              local
8ec9339ee789        bridge              bridge              local
4c4dc85139ab        host                host                local
ca2bdc648e9f        none                null                local
585545f54602        my-network          bridge              local
```

I'm setting the `NetworkId` environment variable for the `edgeAgent` in my Azure portal. No matter if I set it to `my-network` or `585545f54602`, new modules always launch into the `azure-iot-edge` network.

Am I missing something about the way this is supposed to work, or is there a better way to achieve the results I'm after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to specify the network in the config file for the IoT Edge daemon. This file is normally located at `/etc/iotedge/config.yaml`.

The `network` setting in the `moby_runtime` section should achieve what you want:

```
moby_runtime:
  uri: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  network: "my-network"
```

This will set the env variable in the Edge Agent correctly and cascade this network config to all other containers.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that worked for me when the `my-network` did not pre-exist...in which case it created it. However, I'm trying to set up the container network separately, and have it simply add the modules to it. If I create the network, `iotedge` throws a "Container runtime error" "caused by: Serde error", and fails to start.